# How to nicely place two heaps next to each other

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees

I am quite new to latex and I have a question on how to place two heaps of this size nicely next to each other in latex. For example:

```
\[\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw},level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm}]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle,draw]
    \node {7}
           child{node{12}
             child{node{25}} child{node{14}}}
           child{node{9}}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}\]


\[\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw},level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm}]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle,draw]
    \node {7}
           child{node{12}
             child{node{25}} child{node{14}}}
           child{node{9}
             child{node{41}}}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}\]
```

Comment: Welcome! I've formatted your code for you, but could you complete it so we can compile it? Also, why are your `tikzpicture`s in maths mode? Don't leave blank lines between if you want them next to each other: a blank line is a paragraph break. And note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

A blank line is mark-up for a paragraph break. As you probably know, it is the standard, recommended way to indicate that a new paragraph is required in text. It is no different here.

Moreover, `\[...\]` puts the contents in display maths mode, which will centre the contents with vertical space above and below.

You don't need to put a `tikzpicture` in maths mode and it is probably a bad idea. So just don't use `\[...\]` and remove the blank lines.

`\tikzstyle{}` is deprecated and, in your examples, is simply repeating settings you've already configured anyway.

To keep formatting of the 'heap's consistent, consider using a TikZ style, set here using `\tikzset` and named `heap`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  heap/.style={
    every node/.style={circle,draw},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[heap]
  \node {7}
  child{node{12}
    child{node{25}} child{node{14}}}
  child{node{9}}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[heap]
  \node {7}
  child{node{12}
    child{node{25}} child{node{14}}}
  child{node{9}
    child{node{41}}}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 2 heaps]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the qtree package easily

```
\usepackage{qtree}
\begin{document}
\Tree [.7   [ [ 35 ].26 46 ].24 [ 30 ].17 23  ]
\Tree [.18 [ 52 ].21 39  ]
\Tree [.38 41 ]
\end{document}
```